# Noob HTML help: IE8 Compatibility mode problem with Silverlight 3 app

Tags: html, silverlight

If you look at this website with IE8 there a scrollbar on the right... How can I get rid of it? Any ideas pr tools that could help me find the error?

http://www.photocabana.net/

- Does not work with IE8 Compat Mode = Off
- Works in IE8 Compat Mode = On
- Works in Firefox
- Works in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `overflow:hidden` on the HTML element and the BODY that should get it working in IE7 also.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for your site if it's IE7 compatible already is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374783(VS.85).aspx

This will buy you time until you can get everything right in IE8 native.

Answer (score 0):

include this in your `<head>` element:

```
<style>
html, body {
overlow-y: hidden;
}
</style>
```

This is css that hide the scrollbar in the html and body tags.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp